# Tell doctrine that a field can be null

Tags: php, doctrine, entity, symfony

What do I have to enter in the annotation of a doctrine entity.

Its actually like this...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $name;
```

I have to tell doctrine something like `canBeNull=true`. Otherwhise I always get this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null`

But whats the code?

Comment: @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, **nullable=true**)

Comment: if you googled 'doctrine column null' it'd be the first result, on that doctrine page, search 'null'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the attribute **nullable** in the COLUMN property with **true**.

Example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $name;
```